# Why am I getting a syntax error in this simple python print program?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a name in ASCII but keep getting an error.

```
print ("   ---", "  _",  "|\  |", "   ___  ", " |")
print (" |  | ", " | |", "| \ |", "  /   \ ", " |")
print (" |---", "  ---", "|  \|", " /_____\", " |____",)
print ("                           /       \", "|   |")
```

The error message is:

```
File "C:File "C:\[path]\jonah.py", line 3, in ?
  print (" |---", " ---", "| \|", " /_____\", " |____",)

Syntax Error: EOL while scanning string literal: C:\[path]\jonah.py, line 3, pos 57
print (" |---", " ---", "| \|", " /_____\", " |____",)
```

Comment: Why would you not believe your mother?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your \ characters. Also, remove the **,** before closing the parentheses on your third line.  PS Try using `""" your very long string that can span multiple lines """`

Answer (score 1):

In python strings (and most other languages), the `\` character serves a particular purpose - it escapes other special characters, allowing you to put them in your string. Otherwise you'd have a hard time having (for example, there are other escape codes available) both `'` and `"` in the same string:

```
foo = "'\""
# gives a string with the content '"
```

The error message from python tells you that it can't find the end of the string literal, which is caused by:

```
" /_____\"
```

Since the last `\` *escapes* the next `"` and makes it part of the string, the number of `"`'s that delimit the actual string is unbalanced, and thus, python complains.

So what do you do when you need an actual `\` and don't want it to escape something else? You escape it! So if you'd use `\\` instead above, the following `\` would be used verbatim in your string, instead of escaping the next `"`.

In addition - to make it easier to make ASCII art, you can use `"""` to delimit a multi line string:

```
foo = """
This can span many lines
Yup
   Yup
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 to end a line that doesn't end with a new line character you need to use also you need to escape your \ character with another \

```
print (" |---", "  ---", "|  \|", " /_____\\", " |____",end='')
```

You specified the python 2 way of doing it by just using

```
print 'text',
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma at the end of your thid line

```
print (" |---", "  ---", "|  \|", " /_____\", " |____",) <--- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You used [Escape Characters](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) before double quote.

```
print (" |---", "  ---", "|  \|", " /_____\\", " |____",)
```